# Linq - how to group by a 'let' value and sum another 'let' value

Tags: c#, linq

I am consuming an API which I have no control over which returns data from a SQL server as a `List<string>` and each string has the columns as comma separated.

This particular data set is returned as a `varchar` and `datetime` like so:

```
{
    "Prefix_IdentifierA,1/1/1900 12:30:00 AM,", 
    "Prefix_IdentifierA,1/1/1900 12:15:00 AM,", 
    "Prefix_IdentifierB,1/1/1900 01:00:00 AM,", 
    "Prefix_IdentifierB,1/1/1900 12:45:00 AM,"
}
```

The `datetime` represents a time only, hence all of the dates are the same.

I need to convert that into a collection of objects with a total duration per identifier:

```
public class Log
{
    public string Identifier { get; set; }

    public int DurationInSeconds { get; set; }
}
```

So the resulting collection should look like this:

```
{
    Log { Identifier = "IdentifierA", DurationInSeconds = 45 },
    Log { Identifier = "IdentifierB", DurationInSeconds = 105 }
}
```

At present I am doing this in 2 Linq queries:

1) Extract the `Identifier` and `DurationInSeconds` from each of the rows:

```
var logs1 = (from row in rows
             select row.Split(',')
             into columns
             let identifier = columns[0].Replace("Prefix_", string.Empty)
             let duration = DateTime.Parse(columns[1])
             let durationInSeconds = duration.Hour * 3600 + duration.Minute * 60 + duration.Second
             select new { Identifier = identifier, DurationInSeconds = durationInSeconds }).ToList();
```

2) Grouping by `Identifier` and sum `DurationInSeconds`:

```
var logs2 = (from log in logs1
             group log by log.Identifier
             into grouping
             orderby grouping.Key
             select new Log { Identifier = grouping.Key, DurationInSeconds = grouping.Sum(log => log.DurationInSeconds) }).ToList();
```

The Anonymous type from the first query is the same as the `Log` object so is there any way to merge these 2 queries into one?

**EDIT:** My progress so far

I have got as far as grouping by `identifier` but cannot work out how to then get the sum of the `durationInSeconds`:

```
var logs = (from row in rows
            select row.Split(',')
            into columns
            let identifier = columns[0].Replace("Prefix_", string.Empty)
            let duration = DateTime.Parse(columns[1])
            let durationInSeconds = duration.Hour * 3600 + duration.Minute * 60 + duration.Second
            group rows by identifier
            into grouping
            select new { Identifier = grouping.Key, DurationInSeconds = grouping.Sum(?????) }).ToList();
```

Comment: Hey, I undeleted my post. I wasn't sure that it satisfies your question (at least partially).

Comment: @Kapol - thanks, I have edited again and will comment on your answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can group by `identifier` which returns `IGrouping<IEnumarable<T>>`, so you can fetch the Identifier from this which is nothing but the `Key`, next you can again project the `IEnumarable` present for each identifier and parse the `duration` variable there itself. Please note no need to store it before grouping the data.

This query should work fine for you :-

```
var logs =  (from row in rows
            select row.Split(',') into columns
            let identifier = columns[0].Replace("Prefix_", string.Empty)
            group columns by identifier into g
            select new Log { 
                  Identifier = g.Key, 
                  DurationInSeconds = (from dur in g
                                      let duration = DateTime.Parse(dur[1])
                                      select duration.Hour * 3600 + duration.Minute * 60 
                                              + duration.Second).Sum()
                           }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

How about combining query syntax with method syntax?

```
(...)select new { Identifier = identifier, DurationInSeconds = durationInSeconds }).GroupBy(l => l.Identifier)(...)
```

Comment: This works, but I would be interested to know if there is a linq only answer. For those who are interested, here is the actual full Lambda that works: `.GroupBy(log => log.Identifier).Select(grouping => new Log { Identifier = grouping.Key, DurationInSeconds = grouping.Sum(log => log.DurationInSeconds) }).ToList();`